# starting iphone only app on ipad (1x/2x mode) from landscape ignores orientation setting of root view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, orientation, rootview

The iPhone app should mostly be used in portrait mode, but for two views rotation to landscape is allowed. So in the settings all orientations are allowed and in most views, including the root view, rotation is prohibited. Everything works as expected on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 plus. On latter even when the app is started from landscape mode: it shows up in portrait mode. But it does not work on the iPad with the iPad's iPhone-emulation-mode ("1x/2x mode"). When I start the app from the desktop in landscape mode it is presented in landscape mode. This is true for ios 7 and ios 8.
Before I post a lot of code, maybe someone has come across this case before and knows a simple solution?

Comment: did you find a fix for this?

Comment: no. actually not. the "solution" so far is to disallow landscape mode app-wide.